# Mii changed on my 3DS

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, wii-u, nintendo-network-id

So I have had my 3DS for about three years now as well as a Nintendo Network ID. My little brother was recently given a Wii U and being the kind older sister I am, set it up for him on my Nintendo ID.

Well, about a week later, my Mii on my 3DS changed to the one he has on the Wii U instead of my own and I can't seem to change this. My personal settings are still the same, yet my name and character has changed.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Only one Mii and username can be associated with a Nintendo Network ID at a time. If it is changed on one device, it automatically changes on the other. You have two options:

- Use the same Mii and username as your brother
- Create a new NNID and associate it with the Wii U. You can find [instructions for this on Nintendo's website](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1087/p/431/c/495).

Good luck! Feel free to ask in the comments if you have any problems.

Comment: "Use the same Mii as your brother" How is this an option?

Comment: "Create a new NNID and associate it with the Wii U." You would lose everything on the Wii U, and if you'd associate it with the 3DS you'd lose everything on that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a seperate Nintendo Network ID per person, otherwise this will happen.

If he hasn't played on the Wii U yet, you can just delete his profile and then create a new profile with his own Nintendo Network ID. After that, you should be set your own ID's Mii again.

If he has already played on it, then you have a huge problem now because deleting the profile will also delete all the save data. You'll need to contact Nintendo and ask if they can unlink the Nintendo Network ID without deleting the profile so that you can assign a new one. Nintendo customer service can be really frustrating to deal with though :-(